# tailwind and mui style not working in next13.4

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css, next.js13

in my project in first route styles working but nested route styles of mui and tailwind not working.

i use mui v4.

and in this project our senior use page route and app route together and i don't understatnd this.

my component code of route /dashboard/profile/customers:

```
'use client';

import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, Typography, Box, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core';

const customersPage = () => {
  
  return (
    <div className="mt-[157px] flex justify-center">
      <div className="bg-green-400">salam ? ya na salam ?</div>
      <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ color: '#ghdk45', backgorund: 'yellow' }} color="yellow">
        {' '}
        it is a paragraph{' '}
      </Typography>

      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>salaaaa</TableCell>
            <TableCell>salaaaa</TableCell>
            <TableCell>salaaaa</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableCell>ke chetoorii</TableCell>
          <TableCell>ke chetoorii</TableCell>
          <TableCell>ke chetoorii</TableCell>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

      <Box p="1rem" color="red" sx={{ color: 'yellow', marginLeft: '15px' }}>
        Give me some space!
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default customersPage;
```

color or any styles not working .

also my config file of tailwind :

```
const config = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',

  './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'
],

...  // other config 
}
```

i use src folder.